# Virtual hosts redirecting to wrong domain

Tags: apache2, virtualhost

I had multiple virtual hosts and everything was working perfectly, I added an extra one today and now all my previous hosts redirect to the new one.

This is what I get when I run apache2ctl -S

```
   AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
VirtualHost configuration:
104.131.79.162:443     domain1.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/domain1.com-le-ssl.conf:2)
104.131.79.162:80      domain1.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/domain1.com.conf:2)
*:443                  is a NameVirtualHost
         default server domain2 (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/domain2.com-le-ssl.conf:2)
         port 443 namevhost domain2.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/domain2.com-le-ssl.conf:2)
                 alias www.domain2.com
         port 443 namevhost domain3.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/domain3.com-le-ssl.conf:2)
                 alias www.domain3.com
         port 443 namevhost domain4.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/domain4.com-le-ssl.conf:2)
                 alias www.domain4.com
         port 443 namevhost domain1.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/domain1.com-le-ssl.conf:2)
                 alias www.domain1.com
                 alias domain1.com
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server domain2.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/domain2.com.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost domain2.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/domain2.com.conf:1)
                 alias www.domain2.com
         port 80 namevhost domain3.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/domain3.com.conf:1)
                 alias www.domain3.com
         port 80 namevhost domain4.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/domain4.com.conf:1)
                 alias www.domain4.com
         port 80 namevhost domain1.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/domain1.com.conf:2)
                 alias www.domain1.com
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-stapling-refresh: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-stapling: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-cache: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/var/lock/apache2" mechanism=fcntl
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="www-data" id=33
Group: name="www-data" id=33
```

Any idea what's going on?

---

Edit:

Last added vhost config is the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin myemail@mail.com
    ServerName domain1.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/domain1.com/public_html

        <Directory /var/www/domain1.com/public_html/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        <IfModule mod_dir.c>
            DirectoryIndex index.php index.pl index.cgi index.html index.xhtml index.htm
        </IfModule>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Can you add the new vhost configuration?

Comment: just added it, but there shouldn't be anything weird